# How do I find out if an address belongs to me

Tags: wallet-recovery

1CK6KHY6MHgYvmRQ4PAafKYDrg1ejbH1cE I believe is an old block chain address of mine

Comment: Unless you are the pool manager of Slush Pool, it seems very unlikely.

Comment: [Click here](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/1CK6KHY6MHgYvmRQ4PAafKYDrg1ejbH1cE) to see the transaction history for that address.

Answer (score 2):

An address cannot 'belong to someone', but you could be in possession of the private key which allows you to spend from it. So if you have the private key (ie, you have access to the wallet that created that address, or a backup of it), then you can claim any coins held at that address.

Comment: This is like saying: "A safe does not belong to anybody, but you could be in possession of its key that allows you to take money from it".

Answer (score 0):

Thats a Legacy Key, long Time ago they where the only ones wich you could Verify Transactions.
Soon they gonna Veanish complete and the bech32 Keys will be Master.